# Create a TOC with Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I use Report Builder 3.0 for SQL Server 2012 with Reporting Services.

I know there is no TOC function out of the box - only the "Bookmarks" but I want to render my own TOC with page numbers.

I got a tablix object ("Tablix1") which renders all persons in the database with the usual stuff like name, gebdat, telnr, ...

At least I got two ideas, how to achieve a TOC

**first.** For each person, I add a hidden cell with the current page number of this element.

This is my function for the current page number ...

```
Function PageNumber() As String    
    Return Me.Report.Globals!PageNumber    
End Function
```

For each person the cell (`txtPageNumber`) got the right `Pagenumber` - this works perfect.

The only problem is, how can I generate another tablix outside of the current tablix (`Tablix1`) and iterate each person and print the value of the cell (`txtPageNumber`)?

I don't know how to get a reference in the code behind to my tablix (`Tablix1`) ... if I get a reference, I can iterate with foreach ...

I just need to access the cell (`txtPageNumber`) from outside of the tablix ...

**second.** Is it possible to iterate all Tablix objects of my current report and print the value of the `Objectname` and / or their `PageName`? If I can print the `PageName`, I can set the value of the `PageName` to `[=code.PageNumber]` and print all tablix objects with their `Name` and `PageName` property - with this I also get a small TOC which contains my main objects ...

I did a very long research - and did not find any solutions ...

Thank you.